# SceneKit transparent node, transparent material

Tags: ios, scenekit

I try to create two node, one with transparent and one is nomal. There're same position nodes.
Code like following

```
//UIBezierPath *aPath = ....
// add transparent node
SCNMaterial *transparentMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
UIImage *checkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.png"];
transparentMaterial.diffuse.contents = checkImage;

SCNShape *transparentGeometry = [SCNShape shapeWithPath:aPath extrusionDepth:0.000001];
transparentMaterial.transparency = 0.000001;
transparentGeometry.materials = @[transparentMaterial];
SCNNode *transparentNode = [SCNNode new];
transparentNode.geometry = transparentGeometry;
transparentNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);
[root addChildNode:transparentNode];

// addd node
SCNMaterial *materal = [SCNMaterial material];
UIImage *checkImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.png"];
materal.diffuse.contents = checkImage1;
SCNShape *geometry = [SCNShape shapeWithPath:aPath extrusionDepth:0.00001];
geometry.materials = @[materal];
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode new];
node.geometry = geometry;
node.transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0), M_PI_2 , 0, 0, 1);
[root addChildNode:node];
```

the problem is I can look through visible node via transparent node. Problem only occurred when visible node has material with image that has alpha channel inside (like my example image, it's has clear background).

[image]

it's bug of SceneKit? any help would be appreciated!

here is resource of image "tree.png"
[image]

Comment: What do you expect to see when you place a transparent object and a non-transparent object at the same location?

Comment: @0x141E sorry my question maybe not clear enough. This problem occurred when two nodes cross together, as You can see two node cross M_PI_2 radians together. I just want to add one transparent node to the scene.

Comment: If you want a transparent node, why are you attatching a geometry to it?

Comment: @orangenkopf I want to cast shadow from transparent node, when I set transparent to value too small like 0.000001, It's transparent but cant cast shadow

Comment: @larva Anybody got a workaround or solution? I have the same problem. I made a quick app to show the bug in SceneKit [here](https://github.com/multitudes/SceneKitTransparencyBug/blob/main/README.md)